Parachain stopped producing block with: Failed to finalize election round. reason ElectionError::Fallback("`NoElection` cannot do anything.")
My config:
Relay chain - Westend local
Parachain1 - Westmint
Parachain2 - Custom parachain
I have launched relay chain and parachains then reserved paraId for my parachains.
Connected parachains to relay chain and parachains started to produce and finalize blocks. After some time I've got this message on relay chain:
2024-04-29 09:59:54 [#172778]   Failed to finalize election round. reason ElectionError::Fallback("`NoElection` cannot do anything.")    
And also got this message on my parachains and after it parachains stopped block production and finalization.
I tried to change tyep Fallback from pallet_election_provider_multi_phase to
 type Fallback = onchain::OnChainExecution<OnChainSeqPhragmen>;
But it didn't help me at all.
Why it can happen and how can I fix this error?
